# How to open a Jframe which is in another class as a constructor with actionListener?

Tags: java, swing

Basically I have 1 main class which extends JFrame and implements ActionListener and i have created a window which is my main window. Now I wanted to make another window which opens when I click a button on the main window. So to do this I created another class which extends JFrame and created another window. Now I am unsure how to set it so that the new window I created opens when I click a button in the main window. I have my actionPerformed in that main class. Im not sure what statement would make my window pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when the button is clicked you want actionPerformed() to be called. But the button is in SlotMachine so actionPerformed() needs to be in the SlotMachine class as well. You didn't post SlotMachine but it would look something like this:

```
public class SlotMachine extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SlotMachine mainFrame = new SlotMachine();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(640, 480);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen        
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public SlotMachine() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Open new window");
        button.setActionCommand("Add Credits");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String butonCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if (butonCommand.equals("Add Credits")) {
            AddCreditsClass addCredits = new AddCreditsClass();
            addCredits.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
            addCredits.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In SlotMachine's constructor we add a button and add a listener to the button. So when that button is pressed actionPerformed() will be called. And as you can see in actionPerformed() we create a new instance of AddCreditsClass and make it visible.

We moved most code from AddCreditsClass to SlotMachine but what is left looks like this:

```
public class AddCreditsClass extends JFrame {
    public static final int WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    private static JLabel addCreditsLabel;

    public AddCreditsClass() {
        super("Add Credits");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);        
        setLayout(null);        
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much. Could you please tell me what does this "addCreditsFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(this);" do?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that. It centers the window in relation to another. If you do setLocationRelativeTo(null) it will center it on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is have a listener on the main window "Add credits" button. That is, you want to implement ActionListener in your SlotMachine class (that's the class containing the button, right?).
You will indeed want to add this code to your SlotMachine class, and not in the other one :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String butonCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    if(butonCommand.equals("Add Credits")){
        // The add credits button has been fired. Make the other window visible
    }
}
```

You want to make the add credits window visible, that is, you want to do the following :

```
addCreditsFrame.setVisible(true);
```

If you add the listener in your main class, it needs to have access to the frame that has to be visible. You need to send a new AddCreditsClass to your SlotMachine constructor so he can set it visible. You can't use AddCreditsClass.setVisible(true) because you're setting a frame visible, not the entire class.
That is, something along the lines of :

```
public class SlotMachine {
    AddCreditsClass otherframe;
    public SlotMachine(AddCreditsClass otherFrame) {
        this.otherFrame=otherFrame;
        // ...
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String butonCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if(butonCommand.equals("Add Credits")){
            otherFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

You would have the following code :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        SlotMachine mainFrame = new SlotMachine(new AddCreditsClass());
        mainFrame.setVisible(true); // The main window has to be visible at the beginning   

public class AddCreditsClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static final int WIDTH = 700;
public static final int HEIGHT = 500;

private static JLabel addCreditsLabel;

public AddCreditsClass(){
    super("Add Credits");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setLayout(null);
    // setVisible(true); Do _not_ do this! You want the window to be hidden until you set it visible by yourself.
    }
    // No listener here, the button listener should be in the main class
}
```

In your SlotMachine class, which contains the "add credits" button, you would add the listener I mentioned earlier :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String butonCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    if(butonCommand.equals("Add Credits")){
        addCreditsFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Duh! Sorry I hadn't seen you answered before me. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: I find it is very useful to read about the same topic from different sources. So no, absolutely not. :)